# How to change path of main.js on vue-cli?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, webpack, web-config

I use vue-cli

I want to change path of main.js and other vue source file

So, i tried to change build/webpack.base.conf.js

like this.(it is part of build/webpack.base.conf.js

(before)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
```

(after)

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: '../src/main.js'
  },
```

and i tried to start

```
npm run dev
```

but it does not work

it print out this error message

```
These dependencies were not found:

* vue in ../src/main.js, ../src/store/index.js and 9 others
* vue-router in ../src/main.js
* vuex-router-sync in ../src/main.js
* es6-promise/auto in ../src/main.js
* vuex in ../src/store/index.js
* !!babel-loader!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./App.vue in ../src/components/App.vue
* !!babel-loader!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Dash.vue in ../src/components/Dash.vue
* !!babel-loader!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Login.vue in ../src/components/Login.vue
* !!babel-loader!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./404.vue in ../src/components/404.vue
* !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Device.vue in ../src/components/views/Device.vue
* !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Messagegt.vue in ../src/components/views/Messagegt.vue
* !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Monitor.vue in ../src/components/views/Monitor.vue
* !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Firewall.vue in ../src/components/views/Firewall.vue
* !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Performance.vue in ../src/components/views/Performance.vue
* !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"id":"data-v-44394314","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./Dash.vue in ../src/components/Dash.vue
* !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"id":"data-v-1db248d7","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./Login.vue in ../src/components/Login.vue
* !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"id":"data-v-808c2e74","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./404.vue in ../src/components/404.vue
* vue-hot-reload-api in ../src/components/App.vue, ../src/components/Dash.vue and 16 others

To install them, you can run: npm install --save vue vue-router vuex-router-sync es6-promise/auto vuex !!babel-loader!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./App.vue !!babel-loader!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Dash.vue !!babel-loader!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Login.vue !!babel-loader!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./404.vue !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Device.vue !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Messagegt.vue !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Monitor.vue !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Firewall.vue !!babel-loader!../../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=script&index=0!./Performance.vue !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"id":"data-v-44394314","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./Dash.vue !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"id":"data-v-1db248d7","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./Login.vue !!vue-style-loader!css-loader?{"minimize":false,"sourceMap":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"id":"data-v-808c2e74","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!../../myVue/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./404.vue vue-hot-reload-api
> Listening at http://localhost:8080
```

How can i change vue source path?

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Is there `main.js` in that path?

The following directory structures are the same:

```
- root direcotry
 - src
     - main.js
 - directory
     - package.json
      - other files..
```

If the `vue` files are in the following path.

```
- root direcotry
 - src
     - main.js
 - directory
     - src
          - App.vue
     - package.json
      - other files..
```

you must load from main.js as `import App from '../directory/src/App.vue'`

but if the `vue` files are in the following path.

```
- root direcotry
 - src
     - main.js
     - App.vue
 - directory
     - package.json
      - other files..
```

you must load from main.js as `import App from './App.vue'`

Wasn't it just to move main.js?

Check main.js.